# Sounds for my javascript game with pure js?

Tags: javascript, audio

Is it possible to play a sound in my javascript game without using anything like flash or a HTML workaround?

When I searched google it gave me various plugins or ways of doing it with flash, but I'd like to do it with pure js, while being able to play many sounds parallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML5 `<audio>` element has [fairly decent support](http://caniuse.com/#search=audio), and there's also an audio API (which allows advanced audio manipulation) lagging somewhat behind.

There's even a [tutorial on using it in a JS game](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/).